# How do I prevent commands from showing up in Bash history?

Tags: bash

Sometimes, when I run commands like `rm -rf XYZ`, I don't want this to be recorded in Bash history, because I might accidentally run the same command again by `reverse-i-search`. Is there a good way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/48769/avoid-to-keep-command-in-history

Comment: While `bash` *may* be used for writing shell scripts (hence programming), this *particular* aspect of it has absolutely nothing to do with programming (history is an interactive-only thing). Voting to close.

Comment: Related: *[Execute command without keeping it in history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121)*

Answer (score 188, accepted):

If you've set the `HISTCONTROL` environment variable to `ignoreboth` (which is usually set by default), commands with a leading space character will not be stored in the history (as well as duplicates).

For example:

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
$ echo test1
$  echo test2
$ history | tail -n2
 1015  echo test1
 1016  history | tail -n2
```

Here is what `man bash` says:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of values includes `ignorespace`, **lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list**.   A  value  of  `ignoredups` causes  lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of `ignoreboth` is shorthand for `ignorespace` and `ignoredups`.  A value of `erasedups` causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value not in the above list is ignored.  If `HISTCONTROL` is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read by the shell parser are saved on the history list, subject  to  the  value  of `HISTIGNORE`.  The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history regardless of the value of `HISTCONTROL`.

See also:

- [Why is bash not storing commands that start with spaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces) at unix SE
- [Why does bash have a HISTCONTROL=ignorespace option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115934/why-does-bash-have-a-histcontrol-ignorespace-option) at unix SE

Answer (score 68):

In your .bashrc/.bash_profile/wherever you want, put `export HISTIGNORE=' *'`. Then just begin any command you want to ignore with one space.

```
$ ls  # goes in history
$  ls # does not
```

Comment: This depends on the value of the `HISTCONTROL` environment variable, which does not necessarily have `ignorespace` set.

Comment: If `HISTCONTROL` contains `ignorespace`, it's actually only redundant to include ` *` in `HISTIGNORE`. The two operate independently.

Answer (score 28):

Even better use `HISTIGNORE`. This allows you to specify a set of patterns to be ignored (such as `rm`). It is better (I think) than just piping all history to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that one :)

Answer (score 27):

```
kill -9 $$
```

I know that is not as best as the previous answers, but this will kill the current Bash shell without saving anything, useful when HISTCONTROL is not set by default, you forgot to set it, or pure and simple you forgot to put a leading space and you just typed in some passwords and don't want them to remain permanently in history.

This is the quick way, and something like erasing the history file is not as good because you need to do it outside a history saving shell (log in as different user and use su/sudo, creating a background job, etc.)

Answer (score 13):

You can do one of two things:

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

Or, begin the command with a space.

Comment: a space before that's awesome

Comment: Some of us think auto-ignoring commands prefixed by a space is a really bad idea and therefore don't have `ignorespace` set by default.

Comment: Setting `HISTFILE` this way prevents storing *any* history, and does not prevent the command from being added to the in-memory history.

Answer (score 6):

Or

```
unset HISTFILE
```

(similar to the previous answer only shorter: export HISTFILE=/dev/null)

Comment: This only affects the on-disk history, not the in-memory history.

Answer (score 3):

I added an "Incognito" functionality to my `.bashrc` for when I want to run some commands without being saved without having to add spaces before each one.

Do note though that the in-memory history of the current terminal session will still be saved, but when I open a *new* terminal the commands issued in a past terminal's incognito session will never be seen because they were never written to the `HISTFILE`.

To your `.bashrc`:

```sh
ignoreHistory="false"
DEFAULT_HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
HISTFILE="$DEFAULT_HISTFILE"

# Toggle incognito mode
incognito() {
    if [[ "$ignoreHistory" == "true" ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[33mExited incognito mode\e[39m"
        ignoreHistory="false"
        HISTFILE="$DEFAULT_HISTFILE"
    else
        echo -e "\e[33mEntered incognito mode\e[39m"
        ignoreHistory="true"
        HISTFILE=/dev/null
    fi
}
```

Nice little utility I think some people may find use in, you can even change the prompt to reflect whether you're in incognito mode or not.

Comment: When toggling back, it seems that the whole history still gets written... even the commands you wrote just after entering incognito mode. At least that is what's happening when using zsh (I had to replace .bash_history with .zsh_history in your code). So I would avoid witching back to non incognito until closing the window or simply delete the else branch.

Comment: to make the toggle back work, probably want to track the number of commands entered (using $HISTCMD or $LINENO, depending on the settings) and then use `history -d <offset>` to delete the lines. Or just use `history -c` and wipe the whole list from memory.

Comment: would `exec $SHELL` be a good 'exit incoginto' method here?

Answer (score 2):

At shell startup, I explicitly cleanup the history from the entries that I don't want to be there. For example, I don't want any `rm -rf` in the history (it's trauma after removing a directory full of results processed overnight, just with a single `Arrow-Up` + `Enter` :)

I put the following snippet in my init file (works with `.zshrc`, should also work with `.bashrc`)

```
# ...
HISTFILE=~/.zshhistory
# ...

# remove dangerous entries from the shell history
temp_histfile="/tmp/$$.temp_histfile"
grep -v -P '^rm .*-rf' $HISTFILE > $temp_histfile
mv $temp_histfile $HISTFILE
```