# Execute a command without keeping it in history

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line

When doing software development, there is often need to include confidential information in command line commands. Typical example is setting credentials for deploying the project to a server as environment variables.

**How can I execute some commands, when I don't want to store them in the command history?**

Nobody must be able to search them in the `.bash_history` file. Is there a way how to execute Bash commands this way?

Comment: This question should probably be moved to ServerFault as this is not "programming" as much as it is "server admin" - but thanks for the question/answer, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Start your command with a space and it won't be included in the history.

Be aware that this does require the environment variable `$HISTCONTROL` to be set.

- Check that the following command returns `ignorespace` or
  `ignoreboth`:

  ```
   echo $HISTCONTROL
  ```
- To add the environment variable if missing, the following line can be added to the Bash profile. E.g., to file `%HOME/.bashrc`.

  ```
   export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
  ```

After [sourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) the profile again, space-prefixed commands will not be written to `$HISTFILE`.

Comment: This doesn't work unless ignorespace is included in $HISTCONTROL - although this is probably the default on most systems.

Comment: Correct. For more details the OP should have a look at HISTCONTROL and HISTIGNORE in the bash man page.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/ - more bash history tips are available here including this method of hiding commands from history

Comment: If you put space before the command, that won't save the command in history for some OS.

Answer (score 70):

In any given Bash session, set the history file to /dev/null by typing:

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

Note that, as pointed out in the comments, this will not write any commands in that session to the history!

Just don't mess with your system administrator's hard work, please ;)

[Doodad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-command-without-keeping-it-in-history/8473154#comment41123530_8473154) is more elegant. Simply unset the variable: `unset HISTFILE` (thanks!)

Comment: This will prevent *all* commands from being logged. It's not what the questioner wants.

Comment: This caused problems for me related to `/dev/null` permissions being set to 0600 on logout. Instead I used `unset HISTFILE`.

Answer (score 47):

```
echo "discreet";history -d $(history 1)
```

Comment: Ooh, per-command control? Nice.

Comment: This doesn't work in `zsh`. It outputs `fc: too many arguments` and does store the command in the history.

Answer (score 29):

An extension of [John Doe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-a-command-without-keeping-it-in-history/33511637#33511637) and [Cédric ROYER's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-a-command-without-keeping-it-in-history/21550455#21550455). But, this seems to work for me.

```
<your_secret_command>; history -d $((HISTCMD-1))
```

You should not see the entry of the command in your history.

Here's the explanation...

The 'history -d' deletes the mentioned entry from the history.

The HISTCMD stores the command_number of the one to be executed next. So, (HISTCMD-1) refers to the last executed command.

*[Remove a certain line from Bash history file](https://superuser.com/a/529193)*

Answer (score 18):

If you are using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) you can run:

```
setopt histignorespace
```

After this is set, each command starting with a *space* will be excluded from history.

You can use **aliases** in `.zshrc` to turn this **on/off**:

```
# Toggle ignore-space. Useful when entering passwords.
alias history-ignore-space-on='\
setopt hist_ignore_space;\
echo "Commands starting with space are now EXCLUDED from history."'

alias history-ignore-space-off='\
unsetopt hist_ignore_space;\
echo "Commands starting with space are now ADDED to history."'
```

Answer (score 11):

You might consider using a shell without history, like perhaps

```
/bin/sh << END
   your commands without history
END
```

(perhaps `/bin/dash` or `/bin/sash` could be more appropriate than `/bin/sh`)

Or even better, use the [batch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) utility, e.g.,

```
batch << EOB
   your commands
EOB
```

The history would then contain `sh` or `batch` which is not very meaningful.

Answer (score 11):

You can start your session with

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null ;history -d $(history 1)
```

then proceed with your sneaky doings. Setting the histfile to `/dev/null` will be logged to the history file, yet this entry will be readily deleted and no traces (at least in the history file) will be shown.

Also, this is non-permanent.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned [by Doodad in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-command-without-keeping-it-in-history/8473154#comment41123530_8473154), `unset HISTFILE` does this nicely, but in case you also want to also delete some history, do `echo $HISTFILE` to get the history file location (usually `~/.bash_history`), `unset HISTFILE`, and edit `~/.bash_history` (or whatever `HISTFILE` was - of course it's now `unset` so you can't read it).

```
$ echo $HISTFILE       # E.g. ~/.bash_history
$ unset HISTFILE
$ vi ~/.bash_history   # Or your preferred editor
```

Then you've edited your history, and the fact that you edited it!

Comment: Tried this on: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)  and it does not work. The commands I used after unset HISTORY were stored in ~/.bash_history

Comment: @Krystian My mistake - I had written "unset HISTORY" when it should be "unset HISTFILE" - corrected. Does it work now? It works on GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: well I am not sure. Simple test: `unset HISTFILE; echo TEST; history` will give you the command `echo TEST` as the previous to last. Although after terminating the session and connecting again, history does not have this entry indeed. So I would say it works :)

Comment: `unset HISTFILE` does not seem to stop commands being recorded in the history in memory, but it does stop them being recorded in whatever file $HISTFILE was. So I guess you still have your local history in memory, but it is not being recorded in a file anymore, which is what you might want! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following command:

```
echo toto; history -d $(history | sed -n '$s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*.*$/\1/p')
```

I think it's a very portable command.

Comment: I've created alias from this: `alias forget="history -d $(history | sed -n '$s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*.*$/\1/p')"` and now You can do it something like this: `mysql -uroot -pSecretPassword ; forget`

Comment: Sorry, but I realise You need to create function instead of alias because of quotation marks change meaning of `$s` and other things in sed. `function forget() { // put code here // }`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can achieve this. This sets the size of the history file to 0:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=0
```

This sets the history file to `/dev/null`, effectively disabling it:

```
export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

For individual commands, you can prefix the command with a space and it won't be saved in the history file. Note that this requires you have the `ignorespace` value included in the `$HISTCONTROL` environment variable (man bash and search for `ignorespace` for more details).

Comment: This will prevent *all* commands from being logged. It's not what the questioner wants.

Comment: Well, I kind of assumed that the questioner would reset the values after doing whatever it was he wanted that shouldn't be logged.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to run:
`$ set +o history`

To see more, run:
`$ man set`

Comment: This disables history for all future commands, not for an individual command. Most people who come here should look at the accepted answer instead.

Comment: This is valid, or okay but incomplete. As long as we add the reverse command `set -x history` afterward, it works.

Comment: I'm reading the manual and it would seem that `set -o history` turns the history back on. Are you sure it's `set -x history`?

Answer (score 1):

This is handy if you want to erase all the history, including the fact that you erased all the history!

```
rm .bash_history;export HISTFILE=/dev/null;exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This command might come in handy. This will not record the command that is executed

```
history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && <Your Command Here>
```