# How to run SQL script in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, command-line

I want to execute a text file containing SQL queries, in MySQL.

I tried to run `source /Desktop/test.sql` and received the error:

> mysql> . \home\sivakumar\Desktop\test.sql ERROR: Failed to open file
>   '\home\sivakumar\Desktop\test.sql', error: 2

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: basically I think this should be the answer here: \. /home/sivakumar/Desktop/test.sql

Answer (score 667):

If you’re at the MySQL command line `mysql>` you have to declare the SQL file as `source`.

```
mysql> source \home\user\Desktop\test.sql;
```

Comment: For mysql 5.6.10 on Mac, no single quotes are needed for the file path.

Comment: for windows, using '/' instead of '\' worked correctly for me.  I got errors when I originally used '/'.  This is what worked for me...source C:/Users/macombers/Downloads/midcoast_db.sql;

Comment: Drop the quotes on ubuntu too (mysql Ver 14.14  debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper)

Comment: What if you don't have the permissions? Is there a way to run sudo?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I’d copy the file to a place you can access it, or change its ownership, then use that instead.

Comment: is there any way to specify relative path than to type the entire absolute path?

Comment: @kapil Relative to what? You’re inside MySQL at this point, so there is no relative I’m afraid.

Comment: @kapil I know this post is pretty old, but if you are in the folder your script is in before you start mysql, you don't need to type the full path.

Comment: what if directory or file name has spaces?

Comment: @Sarah You can use `\ ` before the space, or wrap the filename with `"`.

Comment: $mysql> source /Users/xgqfrms-mbp/Documents/GitHub/cms-koa-server/cms-koa/schema.sql; (macOS)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :D

Answer (score 282):

You have quite a lot of options:

- use the MySQL command line client: `mysql -h hostname -u user database < path/to/test.sql`
- Install the MySQL GUI tools and open your SQL file, then execute it
- Use phpmysql if the database is available via your webserver

Comment: What about the user's password (-p option)?

Comment: @AmirKatz While the password can be given with the `-p` option, this is not recommended: Other users on the same host can use system tools like `ps` to read it in this case.

Comment: @EugenRieck `-p` without an argument prompts for the password to be entered on the next line

Comment: How do I keep `mysql` open after running the script?

Answer (score 197):

you can execute mysql statements that have been written in a text file using the following command:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < text_file
```

if your database has not been created yet, log into your mysql first using:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword
```

then:

```
mysql>CREATE DATABASE a_new_database_name
```

then:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword a_new_database_name < text_file
```

that should do it!

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: on Windows: for the password I had to use quotation marks and NO space to make it work (the password itself did not contain any spaces or special chars):
`mysql -u yourusername -p"yourpassword"`

Comment: If you don't want your password to be on the prompt I believe the method outlined here will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293042/mysqldump-without-the-password-prompt

Comment: What if i dont want to create the database, how to create automatically? I have over 30 databases ☹️

Answer (score 92):

My favorite option to do that will be:

```
 mysql --user="username" --database="databasename" --password="yourpassword" < "filepath"
```

I use it this way because when you string it with "" you avoiding wrong path and mistakes with spaces and - and probably more problems with chars that I did not encounter with.

---

With @elcuco comment I suggest using this command with [space] before so it tell bash to ignore saving it in history, this will work out of the box in most bash.

in case it still saving your command in history please view the following solutions:

[Execute command without keeping it in history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-command-without-keeping-it-in-history)

---

*extra security edit*

Just in case you want to be extra safe you can use the following command and enter the password in the command line input:

```
mysql --user="username" --database="databasename" -p < "filepath"
```

Comment: I would not recommend passing the password to the command line, as it will be saved in the ~/.bash_history, and can be accessed by other programs trough /proc/.

Comment: Excellent advice from @elcuco! Also, probably use another flag after -p (or have that be the last arg) so another parameter is not erroneously taken to be the intended password.

Comment: Please note that, command line arguments are still visible by other users. Example: for i in  /proc/*/cmdline ; do echo $i; cat $i; done

Comment: This is NOT recommencement as you expose your servers password to the console's history

Comment: @AlexiusDiakogiannis can you give me example how can you view the command from history when you execute it with [space] before the command?

Comment: @talsibony This a really bad practice. In order to be safe that your command will not be visible in history you first need to check the value of your HISTCONTROL environment variable. If and only if the value contains ignorespace or ignoreboth then any command starting with a space will not be added to command history.

Comment: @AlexiusDiakogiannis and elcuco here is an edit, now you can chill down the password won't be saved in history in the edit version.

Comment: what if there is no password?

Comment: @alper just remove the -p

Answer (score 71):

All the top answers are good. But just in case someone wants to run the query from a text file on a remote server **AND** save results to a file (instead of showing on console), you can do this:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < query_file > results_file
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think there should be no space between `-p` and the password

Comment: If the purpose of writing to file is taking data dump, I guess `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE /path/to/file.csv` is more efficient way. See options and syntax here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 39):

I came here searching for this answer as well, and here is what I found works the best for me: Note I am using Ubuntu 16.x.x

1. Access mysql using:

`mysql -u <your_user> - p`

2. At the mysql prompt, enter:

`source file_name.sql`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of launching the prompt, it might even be useful to just combine the two steps in a single command: `mysql -u<user> -p -e 'source filename.sql'`

Comment: Thanks, @junix! The **source** option used this way is what I was looking for.

Comment: @junix This solution combines best of both words i.e. not having to enter the interactive mode, and preserve the output formatting.

Comment: @junix how do you stay in interactive mode after that?

Comment: @minseong You don't, as you don't start the client in interactive mode.

Answer (score 30):

**Give the path of .sql file as:**

```
source c:/dump/SQL/file_name.sql;
```

[image: See In The Image:]

Comment: Thanks a ton! this works even if your user does not have SUDO rights and on remote Amazon RDS

Answer (score 26):

instead of redirection I would do the following

```
mysql -h <hostname> -u <username> --password=<password> -D <database> -e 'source <path-to-sql-file>'
```

This will execute the file path-to-sql-file

Comment: It is truly amazing how stupid it is that there is no --file option for mysql...

Answer (score 23):

```
mysql> source C:\Users\admin\Desktop\fn_Split.sql
```

Do not specify single quotes.

If the above command is not working, copy the file to c: drive and try again.
as shown below,

```
mysql> source C:\fn_Split.sql
```

Answer (score 17):

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword database-name < file.sql
```

Answer (score 17):

So many ways to do it.

```
From Workbench: File > Run SQL Script -- then follow prompts

From Windows Command Line:
   Option 1: mysql -u usr -p
             mysql> source file_path.sql
   Option 2: mysql -u usr -p '-e source file_path.sql'
   Option 3: mysql -u usr -p < file_path.sql
   Option 4: put multiple 'source' statements inside of file_path.sql (I do this to drop and recreate schemas/databases which requires multiple files to be run)
             mysql -u usr -p < file_path.sql
```

If you get errors from the command line, make sure you have previously run

```
cd {!!>>mysqld.exe home directory here<<!!}
mysqld.exe --initialize
```

This must be run from within the mysqld.exe directory, hence the CD.

Hope this is helpful and not just redundant.

Comment: thank you for this, option 3 worked for me. where the others before did not do so great.

Answer (score 16):

Never is a good practice to pass the password argument directly from the command line, it is saved in the `~/.bash_history` file and can be accessible from other applications.

Use this instead:

```
mysql -u user --host host --port 9999 database_name < /scripts/script.sql -p
Enter password:
```

Answer (score 12):

From linux 14.04 to MySql 5.7, using `cat` command piped with mysql login:

```
cat /Desktop/test.sql | sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

You can use this method for many MySQL commands to execute directly from Shell. Eg:

```
echo "USE my_db; SHOW tables;" | sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

Make sure you separate your commands with semicolon (';').

I didn't see this approach in the answers above and thought it is a good contribution.

Answer (score 8):

Very likely, you just need to change the slash/blackslash:
from

```
 \home\sivakumar\Desktop\test.sql
```

to

```
 /home/sivakumar/Desktop/test.sql
```

So the command would be:

```
source /home/sivakumar/Desktop/test.sql
```

Answer (score 6):

use the following from **mysql command prompt**-

```
source \\home\\user\\Desktop\\test.sql;
```

Use no quotation. Even if the path **contains space(' ')** use **no quotation at all**.

Answer (score 4):

Since `mysql -u yourusername -p yourpassword yourdatabase < text_file` did not work on a remote server (Amazon's EC2)...

Make sure that the Database is created first.

Then:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=your_username --password=your_password your_database_name < pathTofilename.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, I've found this to work vs the aforementioned methods, under Windows in your msql console:

mysql>>`source c://path_to_file//path_to_file//file_name.sql;`

If your root drive isn't called "c" then just interchange with what your drive is called. First try backslashes, if they dont work, try the forward slash. If they also don't work, ensure you have your full file path, the .sql extension on the file name, and if your version insists on semi-colons, ensure it's there and try again.

Comment: Why the double slashes?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying this command :

```bash
mysql -u root -proot -D database < /path/to/script.sql
```

You may get an error like this : if you have special characters, mainly '`'

```bash
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/path/to/script.sql' at line 1
```

**So I would suggest to use a command like this :**

```bash
echo "source /path/to/script.sql" | mysql -u root -proot -D database
```

This command will execute `source /path/to/script.sql` once connected to the server, which execute your script.

Answer (score 1):

[image]If you are here LOOKING FOR A **DRUPAL ENVIRONMENT**

You can run with drush command on your project directory

```
drush sqlc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, and tried all the advice i could get to no avail.

Finally, the problem was that my folder had a space in the folder name which appearing as a forward-slash in the folder path, once i found and removed it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use Bash's Here Strings for an instant SQL execution:

```
mysql -uroot -p <<<"select date(now())"
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings