# import dumb files into mysql5.1 in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, mysql-5.1

I am using mysql5.1 server. I want to import sql dumb file using command prompt. and I also tried the following,

`MySQL> -u {username} -p {database_name} < filename`

am getting an error for the above code.

Comment: and I also tried with `mysqldumb -uroot {username} -proot {database} < {filename}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer for my question. we could import the dumb file in the following way:

1.From the command prompt go to the root of the server

```
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>
```

2.Load the dumb file into the server using following command

```
 bin>mysql -uroot -p<server_password> {database_name} < {complete filepath}
```

**Example**:`bin>MySQL -uroot -ppassword mydb < C:\Users\Anto\Documents\DB_Dumb`

Comment: this is what I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

`filename.sql` should be in server. You can load the data if your `filename.sql` in client.

EDIT:
Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940230/how-can-i-run-a-sql-text-file-on-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Is there a need to specify the file extension also in query?

Comment: I tried the following from your above link
  `MySQL>source < {complete location of the file};`
and am getting an error like
_Failed to open file '{file path}',Error:2_

Comment: where you keep your filename.sql?

Comment: **C:\Users\anto\Desktop\DB_Dumb**

Comment: where is your database...in your local or server. if in server you need to copy the `filename.sql` to server. The server have no access to your local.

Comment: Yeah my database in server. and how to copy this file to server?

Comment: create the same path in server. copy this file and paste in server location. Whats ur email?

Comment: ssarobinson@gmail.com