# Is there a faster way to upload data from R to MySql?

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc, rmysql

I am using the following code to upload a new table into a mysql database.

```
library(RMySql)
library(RODBC)

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
  user = 'user',
  password = 'pw',
  host = 'amazonaws.com',
  dbname = 'db_name')

dbSendQuery(con, "CREATE TABLE table_1 (
        var_1 VARCHAR(50),
        var_2 VARCHAR(50),
        var_3 DOUBLE,
        var_4 DOUBLE);
        ")

channel <- odbcConnect("db name")
sqlSave(channel, dat = df, tablename = "tb_name", rownames = FALSE, append = 
TRUE)
```

The full data set is 68 variables and 5 million rows. It is taking over 90 minutes to upload 50 thousand rows to MySql. Is there a more efficient way to upload the data to MySql. I originally tried `dbWriteTable()` but this would result in an error message saying the connection to the database was lost.

Comment: Yes, their corresponding command-line loaders are often recommended for MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... as the process bulk-updates better that the (possibly line-by-line) operating `sqlSave()` or `dbWriteTable()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a CSV export from R for an import into MySQL with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

```
...
write.csv(df, "/path/to/filename.csv", row.names=FALSE)

dbSendQuery(con, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/filename.csv'
                  INTO TABLE mytable
                  FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
                  ENCLOSED BY '"'
                  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'")
```

Comment: When I use this method I get the error `Error in .local(conn, statement,...): could not run statement: Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm...put this query in an .sql script and run it via [MySQL cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940230/how-can-i-run-a-sql-text-file-on-a-mysql-database) (black box command line). You will call it with `source /path/to/filename.sql; ` If this runs successfully, R is the issue.

Comment: So, I tried `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;` and I got an "Access Denied" error, so it appears the issue is my permissions. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try granting your user such rights/permissions or having the db admin set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable the mysql query log:

```
dbSendQuery(con, "SET GLOBAL general_log = 'off'")
```

I can't tell if your mysql user account has the appropriate permissions to do that, or if it conflicts with your business needs.

Off the top of my head: Otherwise you could try to send the data in say 1000-row batches, using a for- loop in your Rscript, and maybe  option `verbose = true` in your call to `sqlSave`

If you send the data in a single batch, Mysql might try to run the INSERT  as a single transaction ("all-or-nothing") and if it fails it goes into recovery or just fails after inserting some random number of rows.