# How to execute sql file from terminal?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL file saved to my desktop `SQL.sql`. When I run `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot`
 the Mysql monitor starts in the terminal. How do I execute the SQL file from my desktop?

I tried `source user\Desktop\SQL.sql` from this question : [How to run SQL script in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940230/how-to-run-sql-script-in-mysql)
and got

```
ERROR: 
Failed to open file 'user\Desktop\SQL.sql', error: 2
```

[image: terminal]

Should the command be run here or elsewhere?

Comment: Try an absolute path to the SQL file.  I don't know MacOS filesystem structure but it should be something like `/Users/[your username]/Desktop/SQL.sql`.

Comment: nice. think it worked. I still have an error but its only in the SQL file. I will trouble shoot that. thank you!