# how to run consecutive commands in CMD when the first command starts a different instance (e.g. mysql -u root)

Tags: c++, mysql, powershell, cmd, terminal

I'm stuck on a problem where I can't find a reasonable work around.
I'm trying to run multiple commands in the Windows CMD from inside a C++ Program using

```
CreateProcessW(NULL,L"mysql -u root -ptoor && source C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\SWE-Software\Datenbank\datenbank-build.sql", ... );
```

The Problem is that when i run this code (or even when I manually put in the the CMD Window, that the second half of the command won't run since prior to this it changes the "instance?" of the CMD to that of the mysql executable.

How would I fix or work around this?

I know in python you can somewhat simulate typing in a way, which could potentially be a work around here.. But i prefer a simple solution without any external libraries.

EDIT: To clarify the first Command seems to run since I can literally see the new console text of the mysql command. Its just that the second command won't be copied in there. It just stays blank and waits for input.

EDIT: This is the Output I'm getting:
[image]

What I do want is this:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

you can run normal statements in cmd before e.g.`set PATH=\%PATH\%;`

then you would use an operator like `&&`.

When you want to an mysql statement it has a special syntax we can use here:
`mysql -u username -ppassword -e "ANY VALID MYSQL STATEMENT GOES IN HERE"`

e.g.:
`set PATH=\%PATH\%;C:\\mariadb\\bin && mysql -u root -ptoor -e "source C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\SWE-Software\Datenbank\datenbank-build.sql"`

If you encounter problems with your cmd try adding an `cmd /c` at the start of the whole statement.

Also if mysql statement fails replace the path code with a `cd mariaspath\bin`, this made everything work for me.

FINAL CODE AS IT RAN IN CMD `cmd /c set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.10\bin\ && mysql -u root -ptoor -e "source C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\SWE-Software\Datenbank\datenbank-build.sql" -q` (note that those were ofc not hard coded but obtained at runtime.

Comment: The second command won't run if the first command failed. That is what the `&&` does. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command)

Comment: it does run ^^ otherwise I wouldn't see the logged in page of my mysql db

Comment: Maybe you are logged into the database in some other instance.

Comment: @drescherjm not sure what you mean by that.. could you explain?

Comment: I think you were already logged in to the database and this command failed.

Comment: STRONG  SUGGESTION: don't rely on the Windows "CMD" shell.  POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVES: 1) execute the separate commands in a .bat file (or better, a PowerShell script), 2) Replace the single [CreateProcessW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes) with multiple [popen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen) statements.

Comment: @paulsm4 Overall a good suggestion, I will keep this in mind for further projects! In this I would have to create and delete this file by hand which i found to not always be as reliable as simple statements.. but this version would be way more flexible so if I can't figure it out soon, i will try powershell scripts :)

Comment: This answer may be what you want: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825350/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825350/487892)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

- It turns out there is *another* problem that *masked* what *will* become a follow-on problem with `&&`:

  - Your `mysql -u root -ptoor` command enters an *interactive* session, which requires *manual exiting* before processing continues.
  - Once you make this call non-interactive, you need to apply the `cmd /c` fix described below.

However, based on your latest feedback it appears that you mistakenly thought that you could send the `mysql` *command string* that starts with `source ...` to the interactive session via `&&`, which cannot work. If anything, you'd have to provide such a string *via stdin* (`echo source ... | mysql ...`, for which you'd need `cmd /c` too), though the better option is use *arguments*, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825350/487892)<sup>link courtesy of [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm)</sup>.

---

Since you're trying to use a *shell* operator, `&&`, you must *call via that shell's CLI*, i.e. via `cmd /c` on Windows:

```
CreateProcessW(NULL,L"cmd /c mysql -u root -ptoor && source C:\Users\IEUser\Documents\SWE-Software\Datenbank\datenbank-build.sql", ... );
```

As noted, `&&` by design only executes its RHS command if the LHS one signaled success (via an exit code of `0`).

---

As for **what you tried**:

*Without* `cmd /c`, all arguments starting with `&&` are passed *as additional, verbatim arguments to `mysql`*.

Comment: I will try that! This reasoning regarding the && operator makes total sense now! I will try some stuff out and update the Question :) Thank you!

Comment: Sadly this didn't work either :/ I tried it with a single & and && with and without cmd /c at front :/

It just keep getting the output I edited below the question!

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer, this looks like an unrelated problem: your `mysql` call is entering an _interactive session_, which blocks further processing until you _exit it manually_.

Comment: I don't get how this is unrelated? :D It's literally the problem and by that the question..
I would like the statement to work just as if I typed them in one after the other manually :) or any other way i can make this work..

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer, it is unrelated in that _it isn't related to `&&`_, which is _how you framed your question_, and it is the problem that calling via `cmd /c` solves.  Once you solve what is actually your primary problem, you _will_ also need the `cmd /c` fix. Please see my update. I'm not familiar with my `mysql`, but your call appears to be lacking arguments as to what query/ies should be performed. Please see my update.

Comment: Ok now I get what you meant! :) Another commend suggested something you also sort of did, which is an alternative syntax for the mysql statement itself!

I should have thought of that myself but i didn't :D thanks for your clarification!

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer, I gather  that you mistakenly thought that you could send the `mysql` _command string_ that starts with `source ...` to the interactive session via `&&`, which cannot work. If anything, you'd have to provide such a string _via stdin_ (`echo source ... | mysql ...`), though the better option is use _arguments_, as the link that drescherjm pointed you to presumably shows. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer, all in all, your question is an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777).