# Don't save current bash session to history

Tags: bash

I notice that when opening `.bash_history` that it contains only the entries from my previous session, it seems that the current session is appended only on exit. Is there any way to prevent the current session from saving? Even crashing `bash` is an option if one knows how to do that. I found that I can `kill -9` the process, but if there is a better way I would love to know.

Comment: A hackish way to accomplish this is to use `kill -9 $$`. By sending your terminal a SIGKILL, it doesn't get a chance to write to the history file.

Comment: I've summed up everything and given more context in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208927/117471

Comment: Also see [Execute command without keeping it in history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8473121/608639), [How do I prevent commands from showing up in Bash history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475524/608639), [Avoid to keep command in history](https://serverfault.com/q/48769) and friends.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Perhaps more elegant than crashing bash would be to use the `history -c` command to clear the history of the current session. Then, there's nothing to save (it even wipes itself from the history).

Comment: That would also nuke the histfile contents.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Maybe it changed at some point? I'm using bash 4.2.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be the cleanest method!

Comment: On bash 4.3.39, `history -c` doesn't just clear the history of the current session.  It also clears the history read from the start of the history file when bash started.  If you're about to close bash, this doesn't really matter.  This is ONLY in the history buffer in memory - it doesn't actually wipe the history file (likely .bash_history).  Even if you cleanly exit bash, it doesn't nuke the history file.  So if you aren't exiting bash, you can follow it up with a `history -r` to re-read the history file.  Sadly, `history -cr` doesn't do both at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker is being a bit *dramatic* with the word **nuke**. I just tested this on bash 3.2.57. Only the **history buffer in memory** is cleared. This means that up arrow will simply bell. But your `~/.bash_history` is unaffected. Any commands you use after that point go into your **history buffer in memory** and if you exit the shell, they will get **appended** to your `~/.bash_history`. It's like Will Smith in "Men in Black", not Will Smith in "Independence Day".

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, I have no reason for disbelief, but I assume I did actually test it over five years ago before wiring the above. Not that I really remember. Maybe it has something to do with other settings and system defaults are different or have changed…

Comment: When using zsh, this cleared my history. I was able to dump contents from another shell into a backup. I get that this is a question for bash, though a warning might be useful.

Answer (score 118):

Unset the `$HISTFILE` variable

```
$ unset HISTFILE
```

> If HISTFILE is unset, or if the history file is unwritable, the history is not saved.
>   http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_106.html

Comment: Thanks, this is good for Bash versions that nuke the whole history on -c.

Comment: What is the benefit of this vs `history -r`, because with that you'll lose everything you have done since you logged in. But with this you'll lose that and all that you are _going_ to do in the session.

Comment: @Pylinux If you are about to do something dodgy like supply passwords on the command line then you may want to ensure that what you are about to do doesn't get saved if you accidentally close the session before remembering to wipe the history.

Comment: @Malvineous By far the most common usecase; not notising that the therminal has focus instead of the browser, accidentally writing the password in the terminal, and now I have to clean up after my self :-)

Answer (score 30):

I know this is an old thread. Just wanted to add this for completion:

If you just want specific commands not to be saved check if `HISTCONTROL` variable is set:
`HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`
or
`HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`

Every command that starts with a leading space will not be put in the history.

Just my 2 cents.

From: `man bash`

```
HISTCONTROL
    A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the
    history list.  If the list of values includes ignorespace, lines which begin
    with a space character are not saved in the history list.  A value of
    ignoredups causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved.
    A value of ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value
    of erasedups causes all previous lines matching the current line to be
    removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value not in
    the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a
    valid value, all lines read by the shell parser are saved on the history
    list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second and subsequent lines
    of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the
    history regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.
```

Comment: That's a nice one!

Comment: `ignoreboth` will also not put duplicate lines, `ignorespace` will put duplicate lines.

Answer (score 27):

Here is your bash history toolkit...

## Exit bash without writing anything

```
kill -9 $$
```

This is hacky and aggressive. But it's a fun way to end an espionage session.

## Clear history *from memory*

```
history -c
```

This clears **memory** of **all** history. If you hit the up arrow, you get nothing. Your `$HISTFILE` is untouched. You can prove this with...

## Reload history from disk

```
history -r
```

This rereads the `$HISTFILE` and appends it to the history in memory (if there is any). You can do this after `history -c` to regain the ability to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> search or up arrow for previous commands. (You can do this instead of logging out and back in).

**Note:** If you didn't clear history first, this just appends to the current history in memory. This will *obscure* the history so that hitting the up arrow a few times will give you comfort in thinking that what you wanted to hide is *gone*. In reality it is just buried and will be written to disk unless it is deeper than your `$HISTSIZE` or `$HISTFILESIZE`.

## Execute a command without including it in history

> See [th3penguinwhisperer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26844730/117471) for the "set an option to have bash not record commands that are prefixed with a space" solution. I omit that (and the `ignoredups` and `erasedups`) from my list because I think bash history should be journal and not a search index.

```
echo foo bar baz; history -d $(history 1)
```

This uses `history -d` to delete an entry by number. Since only the first argument is used (and others are ignored) we can use the output of `history 1` (which is identical to `history | tail -n 1`) to get the number of the current entry.

Because bash oneliners are single history entries, you can do multiple commands like so:

```
echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; history -d $(history 1)
```

This also works:

```
echo foo \
bar \
baz; history -d $(history 1)
```

Even this works:

```
for x in foo bar baz; do
echo $x
done; history -d $(history 1)
```

## Delete your password (a command, etc.) from your history

If all you are concerned about is getting rid of a single entry, you can use the previous example creatively. Use `history` to find the number of the entry to delete. Then delete it by number. For example...

```
$ history
  1  pwd
  2  date
  3  sudovisudo
  4  hunter2
  5  man history
  6  help history
  7  history
$ history -d 4
```

I hope I don't have to tell you this, but just in case: **Don't grep history for your password.** If you *"really do"* need to search history, do `history | LESSHISTFILE=/dev/null less`, and explicitly do a `/` search.

If you are really embarrassed and want there to be no record of you deleting something from history, you can combined this concept with the last.

```
history -d 4; history -d $(history 1)
```

Or to also get rid of the original mistake...

```
for n in "$(history 1)" 4 3; do history -d $n; done
```

Notice that you have to cycle over the entry numbers in **decending** order because each call to `history -d` pops the entry out of the list and all subsequent entries' numbers decrease by 1. Also, you have to double quote the subshell because `history 1` returns not just the number, but also the command and its arguments, and each would get a separate cycle in the `for` loop. But at this point this is turning into a `bash` lesson and I'll stop.

Comment: Add a space in front of the command, if you want to execute a command without including it in history.  (This feature can be enabled/disabled by `HISTCONTROL`)

Comment: @TianrenLiu that was addressed in [th3penguinwhisperer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26844730/117471) but since you mention it, I also updated my answer to link to their answer.

Answer (score 16):

There's another option, similar to `history -c`, but that does not wipe anything previous to the current session.

It is `history -r`, which reloads the history from the `HISTFILE`, like if you just logged in.

I don't know if this works or is available in any bash version previous to 4.3.11, but I though it would be useful to include it to the list.

Here's an example showing the difference between this command and the `-c` one:

```
user@host:~$ # I Just logged in
user@host:~$ history | tail -n6 # this shows commands from the previous session, which ends at item 4682 as well as from the current one
 4679  2014-08-23 17:15:29 # Previous session
 4680  2014-08-23 17:15:33 # Still the previous session
 4681  2014-08-23 17:15:37 # note the datetime
 4682  2014-08-23 17:15:44 exit
 4683  2014-08-23 17:17:25 # I Just logged in
 4684  2014-08-23 17:19:54 history | tail -n6 # this shows the last command, and the ones from the previous session
user@host:~$ # This is a secret command, so I need to remove the traces of this session
user@host:~$ history -r
user@host:~$ history | tail -n5 # Note that I went back to item 4682, and there are no traces of history -r command
 6242  2014-08-23 17:15:29 # Previous session
 6243  2014-08-23 17:15:33 # Still the previous session
 6244  2014-08-23 17:15:37 # note the datetime
 6245  2014-08-23 17:15:44 exit
 6246  2014-08-23 17:22:26 history | tail -n5 # Note that I went back to item 4682, and there are no traces of history -r command
user@host:~$ history -c # instead if I issue history -c
user@host:~$ history # everything disappears
 5248  2014-08-23 17:23:13 history # everything disappears
user@host:~$
```

Comment: On bash 4.3.39, `history -r` Appends the contents of the history file to the current history list. Can't tell if that's what it was doing when you posted your answer... The history numbers jump around a lot between your commands, but don't double.

Comment: Are you sure it appends them? In bash 4.3.11, the numbers jump forward because the counter is not reset, but it does not actually append the contents to the original ones. Indeed, if you log out and log in, the numbers go back to their original state.

Answer (score 8):

That should do:

```
HISTFILE=
```

unset the HISTFILE.

Comment: Thank you, this works and I will use it for older Bash on some outdated servers.

Comment: You could also try:
unset HISTFILE
It certainly does the trick if you don't want anything of this session to be in the history. Otherwise see my comment above about HISTCONTROL.

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me.

```
 export HISTFILE=/dev/null
```

Note that it has a space in front of it. Most modern distros would not add commands that are entered after a space to bash history. That will prevent that line also from appearing in your history.

Comment: This also makes your existing history unavailable in the session (for example, Ctrl+R reverse search will not work for existing history)

Comment: Not on any Ubuntu installation, I have at home or at work.
Using Ctrl + r still works. It just does not save the exiting terminal's history for this specific session. Nothing else is changed.