# How to execute a command in bash without logging to history?

Tags: linux, bash, history

I've seen that running a command with space before it doesn't log it in history(command at least)
But that doesn't seem to be the Case for PopOS

It worked in Ubuntu but it wasn't working in PopOS.
Is there any workaround or other trick I could try

```sh
$ls
$history
 1 ls
 2 history
```

```sh
$ pwd #there's a space preceding this command
$history
 1 ls
 2 history
 3 pwd
 4 history
```

Works in Ubuntu but doesn't work in POPOS

Comment: Oh dear, yet another distro likely to have a user base in the single digits :-) In any case, not really a programming question, suggest you ask on SuperUser.

Comment: Also see [Execute command without keeping it in history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8473121/608639), [How do I prevent commands from showing up in Bash history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475524/608639), [Don't save current bash session to history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9039107/608639), [Avoid to keep command in history](https://serverfault.com/q/48769) and friends.

Comment: `HISTCONTROL` from the dupe is the right answer for ignoring commands starting with a space. Thanks, @jww

Answer (score 4):

## Use set for this:

```
 set +o history
    do your command you want to be ignored
 set -o history
    now your commands will be stored to history again
```