# Run AWS CLI from local without storing credentials in local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How to run aws cli to download s3 bucket data without storing aws credential in local machine?

Please Note that s3 bucket is not a public bucket.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what your goal is, but you can use [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) which you are only exporting for the current session/aws_cli run.

To prevent in bash (asuming you are using linux) that the export is written to history, you can use a [space infront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473121/execute-a-command-without-keeping-it-in-history/8473153#8473153) of the command.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. @Saurabh Kumar can you please accept this as an answer if this solved your problem just like it did mine?

Answer (score 1):

You can start an EC2 instance and give that instance a role that allows it to read from your S3 bucket. 
Once started, connect to the EC2 instance using ssh and initiate your S3 transfer using `aws s3 cp...ˋ or ˋaws s3 sync...`