# knife bootstrap command without prompting password

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to write a bash script which contains the command for bootstrapping a Ubuntu client node using `knife` command. When I execute the script, the `knife` command was asking the sudo password of client node and once i type the password, it works as expected. But I am looking for an automated way without prompting password. Here is the command I used for bootstrapping.

```
knife bootstrap <IP_ADDRESS> -x <USER_NAME> -P <PASSWORD> --sudo
```

After checking, [knife bootstrap document](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_bootstrap.html), I have tried giving the ssh-password also like below, but with same result.

```
knife bootstrap <IP_ADDRESS> --ssh-user <USER_NAME> --ssh-password <PASSWORD> --sudo
```

What may be wrong with this command. I am expecting the knife command to automatically login to the client and bootstrap, but its asking like,

```
<IP_ADDRESS> knife sudo password:
 Enter your password:
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I made this work.

```
echo <SSH_PASSWORD> | knife bootstrap <IP_ADDRESS> -x <USER_NAME> -P <PASSWORD> --sudo
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure you turn off your bash history, otherwise people could retrieve your password. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475524/making-sure-commands-dont-show-up-in-bash-history

Answer (score 6):

Looking through the doc this may be the parameter you need:

```
--use-sudo-password
```

Although the documentation seems to imply that the password that that will be used is the same for the ssh operation, I don't know if that will be sufficient in your case.

Reference: https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#knife-bootstrap-options

Comment: knife bootstrap -N <NoteName> <NoteIP> --sudo --use-sudo-password <pass> --ssh-user <sshuser> -P <sshpassword> -y --secret-file encrypted_data_bag_secret -r 'role[Myrole]'

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid using passwords , you could set up the ssh keys of your workstation on the chef-node and run the

```
knife bootstrap yourclient.domain.com -x <USER_NAME> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N client1 --sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your command

it should be `--ssh-password`

what you have is `--sh-password`

Comment: Oops..Its a typo error. corrected..I used --ssh-password only. The command is working, only prob is that, its prompting for password.

Comment: What you are doing seems to be correct. I checked http://docs.opscode.com/install_bootstrap.html and see that it also asks for the password even though it is already supplied. Were you able to do it without password in the past? Or is this something your trying to do for hte 1st time?

Comment: I always bootstrap from the node itself so never had to follow this process. Let me know if you find something which resolves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the NOPASSWD option in the [/etc/sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) file. This configures sudo to suppress the password check.

Comment: Nope...not working.I have added NOPASSWD for admin, but still the same. But i guess, this wont be the correct solution even if it works..coz we need to configure these things in client node, before bootstrapping, rt? that kind of tricks are my final option..

Comment: It worries me when you say you added "NOPASSWD" for admin..... Are you also bootstrapping chef using the user "admin"?.... This will work. It may be inconvenient but it has to happen on the node you are connecting to. Allowing a client to disable a security feature from a remote connection would be a bad idea. Think of sudo configuration like the configuration you have to setup for sshd. Create your security policy and bake it into your image.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of authentication happening:

1. The SSH connection (may be via a key or via a password)
2. The `sudo` authentication (usually, a password is required).

When you are first bootstrapping a machine, I don't think you can avoid needing the sudo password.

I've seen Ruby code that can pass a sudo password over the SSH connection (so the user doesn't have to type it in the middle of the command), but I don't think that `knife` has that built in.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be used in this way (worked for me)

```
knife bootstrap $ipaddr --ssh-user $userid --ssh-password $pswd --node-name $hostname --sudo --use-sudo-password -P $pswd
```

> --use-sudo-password
>     It is required to supply password for this option too, in the same way you supply for --ssh-password