# write git username and password in command line without storing my credentials

Tags: git, command-line-arguments

How can I run the following command in one command line?

> prompt> git pull user password

We are using a shared machine in which each user can log in and build his branch. Since it is a shared machine, we do not want to store my credentials in the global configuration. Currently git pull expects user and password in new lines and I hope we can do it in one command line.

Comment: Use SSH keys for authentication instead.

Comment: Thanks. 
1. since i'm not a unix sysadmin, can you give an example how to do it?
2. Does this command line exists (simple solution)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with HTTPS

```
git pull https://user:password@alpha.com/bravo/charlie
```

However be careful, this method can store credentials in `~/.bash_history` or
similar.

[How to prevent commands to show up in bash history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475524/#29188490)

Comment: Also note that program arguments may be available by default to other users (check `ps`).