# How do I set the name of the default profile in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I give the command `aws config list`, I get the following output for the default profile:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
```

However, when I give the command for a named profile, I get a profile name

```
$ aws configure list --profile MyProfile
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                MyProfile           manual    --profile
```

I have tried `aws configure set profile Default` to name the default profile as `Default` by reading the '[set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html)' CLI command, I also tried `aws configure set StoreAs Default` because I thought that's what's the variable is named after I read [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html). I want to do this because I want have two profiles and I want to switch between profiles using the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable.

Comment: Fyi the new equivalent command of `aws config list` is now **`aws configure list`**.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I have multiple profiles too, I use `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` to switch back and forth. However, I've named each profile something descriptive, like `aws-engineering` and `aws-production`. Then, I can use `set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=aws-engineering` and I'm good to go.

I have no DEFAULT profile specified in my `~/.aws/config`, this was intentional so that I always explicitly have to choose which environment I'm working on.

Comment: Not having a default is a clever thing to do! Avoids (potentially costly) accidents due using the wrong profile.

Comment: If you are using bash and want that extra bit of security you could also prefix your command with a space so that bash won't store it in the command history log (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188490/507654)

Comment: This answer is outdated. [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) does not mention `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`. Instead, use `AWS_PROFILE`.

Comment: As @WolfgangKuehn mentioned to use `AWS_PROFILE`, I wanted to point out that if you happen to have both variables defined, you can get unpredictable results. ( I think I was using the var with default, and other things were setting the `AWS_PROFILE`. )

Comment: Use `setx AWS_PROFILE "your_profile_name"` to make the change permanent and system-wide.

Answer (score 72):

Setting the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable at the command line should specify the profile.

See: [Can I specify a default AWS configuration profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35660499/55075)

For example:

#### Linux, macOS, or Unix

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2
```

<sup>Note: To unset, run: `unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`.</sup>

To make the change persistent, add above line into your `~/.bashrc` user's file.

Note: You can also use `AWS_PROFILE`. See: [Named Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html).

#### Windows

```
set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2
```

Source: [User Guide » Configuring the AWS CLI » Named Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html).

See also: [A New and Standardized Way to Manage Credentials in the AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/).

Comment: This answer is outdated; see comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866692/570118).

Answer (score 13):

You just switch to the profile you want (for ex: in Linux use: `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=MyProfile`) and then switch back to the default profile using `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=default`. 'default' is the profile name given to your first profile when you create it.

Comment: This answer is outdated; see comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866692/570118).

Answer (score 11):

in **Windows** if you want to make sure the change of **profile persists** in new command line session better to use setx

```
setx AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE profile_name
```

Remember to to close the command prompt and open a new one (so that changes made are reflected)

Comment: This answer is outdated; see comments on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866692/570118).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set up your own profile as a default one then you should consider making changes to your shell's startup script.

For Powershell, this is how you can do it.

```
$Env:AWS_PROFILE="admin"
```

here the profile name is `admin` .

In Linux and macOS you can do something like this.

```
export AWS_PROFILE=admin
```

if changes persist then everything is good otherwise make changes to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: It's works on PowerShell command. To ensure you could use `aws configure list` the response should be match with your profile.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in the [leading answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37866692/622049) that `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` doesn't always work (that it does not always work is only suggested by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012460/how-do-i-set-the-name-of-the-default-profile-in-aws-cli#comment134457888_37866692)). It in particular doesn't work with the Java SDK, which is quite common. Admittedly, the OP only mentions the CLI, but `AWS_PROFILE` works with the CLI as well as:

- rclone
- terraform
- [this list](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2470)

The question is: what tools only work with `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` but not `AWS_PROFILE`? Can we forget about `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE`? From [Managing AWS environment credentials made easy | AWS in Plain English](https://aws.plainenglish.io/managing-aws-environment-credentials-made-easy-b8e537c7e142):

> The ‘Default’ variants are used by older versions of SDKs.

In practice I've never run into these older SDKs or any other tool that doesn't accept `AWS_PROFILE`.