# Can I specify a default AWS configuration profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-cli

In my development environment, I regularly switch between several AWS access keys. So in my `~/.aws/credentials` file, I have several profiles. I can then use these profiles with aws-cli by specifying the `--profile <name>` flag.

I develop several apps that use the Ruby AWS SDK. They are setup to read credentials from the `~/.aws/credentials` file (the SDK does this by default, see this [configuration article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/latest/DeveloperGuide/aws-ruby-sdk-getting-started.html#aws-ruby-sdk-configuration)).

The problem is that the SDK always reads from the `default` profile. I would like to be able to configure it to read from some of the other profiles. Is this possible?

I've tried setting the default profile in my environment with:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=<profile name>
```

as outlined in [configuring the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles) but it seems that only works with the aws-cli and not with the SDK.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For SDK:

> By setting the AWS_PROFILE environment variable to the profile you
>   want to use.

For CLI:

From: [A New and Standardized Way to Manage Credentials in the AWS SDKs](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs)

> "AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE is correct for the AWS CLI. The AWS CLI respects
>   AWS_PROFILE if it is set, but AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE takes precedence."

Comment: Perfect! `AWS_PROFILE` was what I was looking for.