# AWS CLI - using credentials unable to list buckets, using profile I can list buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to understand a bit the following situation. I have set $HOME/.aws/credentials as follows

```
[aws-users-andres]
aws_access_key_id = accesskey
aws_secret_access_key = UJPYNsecretkey
```

this credentials are refreshed periodically using some scripts and MFA. $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN are set in the environment.

Then I also have $HOME/.aws/config file with a set of profiles that my company is using to access different resources:

```
[profile profile_name]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1464549XXXX:role/profile_name
credential_source = Environment
```

Now if I try to list the buckets:

```
aws s3 ls
```

The output is "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied"

But running using the profile

```
aws s3 ls --profile profile_name
```

I'm able to list the buckets in our S3.

I'd like to list the buckets without specifying the profile or set the default behavior to use `profile_name` . I was recently tasked with a task to periodically sync some google cloud storage bucket with s3 resources, and was following the ideas from here [Exporting data from Google Cloud Storage to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329580/exporting-data-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3) but the gsutil command fails ( Forbidden access to S3 )

I have tried to use AWS_PROFILE and AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE env var set as `profile_name` but  that doesn't seem to work.

I appreciate any help and guidance. I could write some ad hoc script to copy and upload the needed files from gcloud to s3 but I was hoping gsutil would be a better option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux or Mac, you can create an alias like so: `alias s3list='aws s3 ls --profile profile_name'`. After that, you can type s3list to list the buckets. You can also create an environment variable like so: `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=profile_name`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012460 and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-alias-command

Comment: You can just modify the `config` file and name the profile `default` -- it will then be used by default! Use `[default]` (not `[profile default]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline environment variables:

```bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="THISISMYKEY" \
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="THIS_IS_SECRET_KEY" \
aws s3 ls
```

is the quickest but least secure way of doing this. It's insecure because running `history | grep "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"` easily exposes the credentials used.

A better approach is to not use inline shell variables, avoid setting the credentials manually on those places and just utilise the built-in AWS CLI command for configuring profiles for your machine.

```bash
$ aws configure --profile allan
$ AWS Access Key ID [None]: THISISMYKEY
$ AWS Secret Access Key [None]: THIS_IS_SECRET_KEY
$ Default region name [None]: ap-southeast-1
$ Default output format [None]:

aws s3 ls --profile allan
```

If these two options don't work, consider seeking help from the person that issued your AWS credentials. The credentials may be stale, incorrect or lack permissions to query S3 buckets.