# how do I set the default aws user with the CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Been having issues with this for the past hour at least, and so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I am running a windows system using the AWS CLI through windows PowerShell.

I have numerous profiles setup on my system for AWS.  Normally, it is not a problem but today it seems to be.  I need to switch from my default profile to another profile.  Currently when I run `aws configure list` I get the following output:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                      nam           manual    --profile
access_key     ****************KBU2 shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************XLn7 shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

So my default profile is set to nam, which is good.  However, I need to use my profile called "butterfly".  And this is where I am getting stuck.  I can see that my butterfly profile is setup correctly by using `aws configure-list --profile butterfly` which results in:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                butterfly           manual    --profile
access_key     ****************FS7W shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************88vh shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

All the documentation that I have found has suggested that either `set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=butterfly` or `setx AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE butterfly` should do the trick.  However, when I re-run `aws configure list` after setting, I am still getting the previous output and no profile change.

My end goal is I need to connect several IoT devices using AWS.  If I run `aws iot list-things` I get an error exception error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the ListThings operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided
```

That is fine and I am not concerned about that.  However, if I adjust my call and add a profile `aws iot list-things --profile butterfly` I then get a list of my IoT devices.
I will be using mongoose os part of the software on these boards.  https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/cloud/aws.md  Where I am getting stuck with the profile is on the second step "setup device", with the provision AWS IoT.

**EDIT**
Looking at the link in the first comment, I tried to set all the variables individually with:

```
setx AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
setx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
setx AWS_DEFAULT_REGION us-west-2
```

That still didn't do anything as when I list I still have nam.

I am cleary missing a step, just not sure what.

Comment: Which document are you looking at? AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE is not listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). Suspect this is legacy. Use AWS_PROFILE.

Comment: @jarmod I have been looking at many different pages and SO answers.  I got the idea for AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012460/how-do-i-set-the-name-of-the-default-profile-in-aws-cli.  I also updated my question at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE is not listed at [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). It is no longer supported. Arguably, it never made a lot of sense in the first place.

Use AWS_PROFILE instead.

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention back to that.  I have looked over that page, a bunch of times.  Each time I was missing this one crucial sentence: " It does not affect any command shell that is already".  I have been so busy and focused I never reset my console.