# How to pass a user / password in ansible command

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I want to use Ansible as part of another Python software. in that software I have a hosts list with their user / password.

Is there a way to pass the user / pass of the SSH connection to the Ansible ad-hoc command or write it in any file in encrypted way?

Or do i understand it all wrong, and the only way to do it is with SSH certification?

Comment: You don't want to store passwords on a computer. That's terrible security practice. :-)  Instead, use SSH keys for authentication. The [SSH documentation](http://www.openssh.com/manual.html) includes everything you need, in particular [ssh-keygen](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen). Create your key, then add the public part (i.e. `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`) to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on each target host.

Comment: You can use vault to store data encrypted (AES-256) but I'm not sure you can pass the password if not by typing it (see my answer)

Comment: user5507598, yes its possible, you need to use vault key-file and call ansible-playbook as command with -k for expect module and for responses:  (?i)SSH password: "{{ password }}" . The variable containing encrypted password will be de-crypted with vault. Though this will keep the lock and key both at the server. not the best way.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[The docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-1) say you can specify the password via the command line:

> `-k`, `--ask-pass`.
> ask for connection password

Ansible can also store the password in the [`ansible_password` variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) on a per-host basis.

Comment: Probably you will need to give a read at [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users) too.

Comment: this works as advertised. you can also store them in an inventory file

Comment: Actually the inventory is a better option yet not so safe so probably you could add those parameters in a script instead (where they can be decrypted). [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#non-ssh-connection-types) is how to save the user/pass in the inventory: `ansible_user`, `ansible_ssh_pass`

Comment: storing the values in inventory is a really bad idea for security unless you encrypt it with vault.

Comment: Agreed. And still is a bad idea for practicality, the inventory is often the part that changes the most.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!   currently i have in my software an encrypted file with the user and passwords. As far as i understand,  --ask-pass will prompt wait for a password, and even if scripted, it might be easy to track and would be security vulnerable. Regarding inventory i think i missed the point. how can i use the inventory file with encrypted password? when shall i decrypt them?

Comment: Following @smiller171's approach all you need is to encrypt the inventory using [vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html). Afterwards, you can run your playbook with the `--ask-vault-pass` option for Ansible to prompt for your passphrase (so it can decrypt files) before running all the tasks.

Comment: @user5507598 so the ssh password is automatically input with the need for interactive typing if we use vault?

Comment: Storing the defaulte SONiC password in my inventory for the inventory that provisions my ssh keys on a switch doesn't decrease security and is less annoying than having to encrypt it.  There are cases (provisioning something better after install) where inventory is the right answer.

Answer (score 51):

You can use `--extra-vars` like this:

```bash
ansible all --inventory=10.0.1.2, -m ping \
  --extra-vars "ansible_user=root ansible_password=yourpassword"
```

If you're authenticating to a Linux host that's joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain, this command line works.

```bash
ansible --module-name ping \
  --extra-vars 'ansible_user=domain\user ansible_password=PASSWORD' \ 
  --inventory 10.10.6.184, all
```

Comment: ... and then your credentials go to bash history :/ Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1053510 You can temporarily disable bash history with an environment variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475524/how-do-i-prevent-commands-from-showing-up-in-bash-history

Comment: This solution worked for me, authenticating as an Active Directory user from a Linux client to a domain-joined Linux client.

Comment: @user1054510 The creds do not go in bash history if you press space first before issuing them.

Comment: Note to self: read the variable names carefully, `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_password` have no effect on the ssh password failures. Make sure you're using `ansible_user` and `ansible_password`.

Comment: @DavidWest Can you explain what you mean by "issuing them"? They are not being prompted and then entered via CLI, they appear as plain text as part of the `ansible` call in `--extra-vars` params, thus landing in the bash history.

Comment: @Koenigsberg, good points. Just adding a space before some command somewhere is vague and not any solution here. I am now considering Francois Swanepoel's answer... seems nice if you want to use this in a script and pass vars in as well. Also... is this what Ansible Vaults are for?

Comment: @DavidWest I am not sufficiently familiar with Ansible Vaults, you may be onto something there

Comment: In my case, the control place user is ansible and the worker node user is root. I installed the public key but it as not working since the users are different in two nodes. I passed the above command without the password and it worked fine. As follows $ ansible all --inventory=10.0.1.2, -m ping \
    --extra-vars "ansible_user=root"

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned before you can use --extra-vars (-e) , but instead of specifying the pwd on the commandline so it doesn't end up in the history files you can save it to an environment variable. This way it also goes away when you close the session.

```
read -s PASS
ansible windows -i hosts -m win_ping -e "ansible_password=$PASS"
```

Answer (score 8):

I used the command

```
ansible -i inventory example -m ping -u <your_user_name> --ask-pass
```

And it will ask for your password.

For anyone who gets the error:

```
to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program
```

On MacOS, you can follow below instructions to install sshpass:

1. Download the [Source Code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)
2. Extract it and cd into the directory
3. ./configure
4. sudo make install

Comment: Found this funny: on MacOS when I `brew search sshpass` I got "We won't add sshpass because it makes it too easy for novice SSH users to
ruin SSH's security." so thanks for the instructions

Answer (score 0):

the most stright forward way with the ansible is to put your vars in an inventory file, i know that there is some cases that the vars should be passed like environment variables or arguments, so make a temp inventory , put the vars inside it , do the job and then remove it if required,

```
#set some test vars in linux environment or load them from a .env file
export server_ip=54.82.65.25
export my_user=foo
export my_pass=bar

#put vars in a temp inventory file
echo "$server_ip ansible_user=$my_user ansible_password=$my_pass" >> tempinventory

#run my_play.yml
ansible-playbook -i tempinventory my_play.yml
```