# Sanitising command before storing it in bash history

Tags: bash

Upon accidentally running the wrong command because of an incomplete `Ctrl-R` search and `rm -rf`ing a file I needed, it got me thinking.

Is there a way to sanitise `rm -rf foo` to be saved in bash history as `rm -r foo`?
This will ensure if the command is accidentally run in the future, it will ask before doing so.
My `rm` is aliased to `rm -iv`, so I think this stops `rm -r` from removing without asking (I admit I have not run `rm -r` without the `-i` flag)

The reason I think this is possible is based on the bash bang builtins.

```
mkdir foo
cd !$
```

Will show in bash history:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
```

Edit: while I appreciate the "don't save in history at all" solutions, I am aware of it and specifically wanted a different solution, as @tripleee explained.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32460/excluding-some-of-the-commands-from-being-getting-stored-in-bash-history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent commands to show up in bash history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475524/how-to-prevent-commands-to-show-up-in-bash-history)

Comment: With your alias, `rm -rf` expands to `rm -iv -rf`, so the `-f` overrides the preceding `-i`.

Comment: While the nominated dupicate is probably the only sane answer (i.e. basically "don't do that") it doesn't directly answer the OP's question.  I interpret this to mean "is there a facility to somehow filter what ends up in the history" (the answer to which is no, though Chepner's answer intriguingly offers a way to do roughly that) rather than "how do I completely remove some commands from the history" (which is a different thing, and easy to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how foolproof this is; it might miss some way of supplying the `-f` option. That said, you can override `rm` with the following:

```
rm () {
  local HISTIGNORE="$HISTIGNORE:command rm *"
  local arg process
  local -a sanitized
  command rm "$@"
  process=true
  for arg in "$@"; do
    if [[ $process && $arg = -*f* ]]; then
      sanitized+=("${arg//f/}")
    elif [[ $arg == -- ]]; then
      process=
    else
      sanitized+=("$arg")
    fi
  done
  history -s rm "${sanitized[@]}"
}
```

This works as follows:

1. Temporarily add the pattern `command rm *` to the `HISTIGNORE` list, so that the command about to be executed isn't added to history.
2. Execute the command as requested.
3. Walk through the arguments, looking for any that contain the `-f` option. (Either standalone or in a cluster of short options.) Any such word should have the `f` removed. Sanitized words are added to a new array.
4. The `history -s` command adds the reconstructed command (with sanitized arguments) to the history list.

Comment: This is a really interesting way to solve this. Because of my alias, this shows in history as `rm -iv -r foo` but it's still excellent. Re-running the command asks me before deleting anything. Thank you.