# Why does "$<space><tab><tab>" perform filename completion?

Tags: bash, tab-completion, bash-completion

While trying to configure the programmable completion, I came across a behavior I don't  understand.

Given those three completion scenarios, this is the way I understand them:

---

```
$<TAB><TAB>
```

Beginning of the line --> use `complete -E` --> if it doesn't exist, use `complete -D` --> if it doesn't exist, use the default Bash completion --> there are no words on the line --> use command completion.

---

```
$com<TAB><TAB>
```

Trying to complete first word --> use command completion.

---

```
$command argu<TAB><TAB>
```

There is at least one word on the line --> trying to complete an argument --> use `complete` for the given *command* --> if it doesn't exist, use `complete -D` --> if it doesn't exist, use the default Bash completion --> there is already at least one word on the line so don't use command completion --> doesn't start with `$`, `~` or `@` so perform filename completion.

---

My question is why is the filename completion performed instead of command completion in this scenario even though there are no words on the line yet:

```
$<SPACE><TAB><TAB>
```

It's even more confusing since the command completion below is performed as expected:

```
$<SPACE>com<TAB><TAB>
```

I most likely misunderstood the manual and I would be most grateful for any explanation.

---

**NOTE:** 
 `$` denotes the prompt, not a literal dollar sign.

Comment: Is the `$` literal (a part of your command that you entered by hand), or are you just using it to represent the command line prompt? For me (using [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)), a literal `$<tab><tab>` shows the list of variables I could complete. `$<space><tab><tab>` assumes `$` is a command without any known parameters and therefore completes with file names by default.

Comment: @AdamKatz It's there to denote the prompt. I get why that might be misleading and will edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you type `complete -p`

Answer (score 2):

When a line starts with a blank in a Bash shell, this tells the shell that the command should not go into the command history. This can be configured by setting the `HISTCONTROL` env variable in your `.bashrc`, `.profile` or whatever file you want and should be the default behavior (see also [How to prevent commands to show up in bash history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475524/how-to-prevent-commands-to-show-up-in-bash-history#6475698)).

So command execution is the same when the line has a leading blank except that this command doesn't go into history. Thus, code completion also behaves the same.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, sorry. So because there is a space, the completion doesn't process commands since space means you don't want them in the command history etc? And how come `$<SPACE>com<TAB><TAB>` works even though there is also a space?

Comment: I believe I've slighty mistaken your question. Maybe this helps you a bit more: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205360/how-does-bash-auto-completion-work#205409 According to (2) you are outside of the context for command completion (since you haven't started a word yet but already typed a character), thus Bash tries to auto-complete filenames. Hope this gives you some guidance :)