# How can I put an sql file into a postgresql database with a command line using URI?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, automation

I've wrote an sql file with some inserts I want to do in my database.

Here's an example of what it's made of :

```sql
-- User
INSERT INTO users (user_id, credit, email, passwd, alias_login, user_id) 
VALUES (1, 250, 'test@test.com', '123456', '1111', 'admin');
```

And I've also wrote a batch script which install my database before and I want after the installation to put some datas inside it with this sql script inside the batch script.

I've already explore all the options and to be fully automatised I need to connect to my db with a string to avoid password typing like that :

```
C:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\15.2\bin\psql.exe "postgres://mydbadmin:mydbadminpasswd@localhost:5432/mydb"
```

But the thing that I want is to input to this my sql script considering that with this string method I can't use the -f option or any -c "\i ..." thing. It just ignores the command.

Also, I've tried this which didn't work at all :

```
type %cd%/myscript.sql | C:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\15.2\bin\psql.exe "postgres://mydbadmin:mydbadminpasswd@localhost:5432/mydb"
```

Comment: What command are you claiming gets ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql -c <command>` works just fine with a connection string URL:

```bash
psql -d "postgresql://user:password@host/dbname" -c "SELECT 42"

 ?column? 
══════════
       42
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the [`PGPASSWORD` environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) or use a [`.pgpass` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) (`pgpass.conf` on Windows).

#### Using `PGPASSWORD`

- On Linux, you could just use:

```bash
PGPASSWORD=mypassword psql -U myuser -f myscript.sql mydb
```

Note: you may want to [take measures so that it doesn't stay in your Bash history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188490/372643).

- On Windows (assuming `cmd.exe`):

```bash
SET PGPASSWORD=mypassword
C:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\15.2\bin\psql.exe -U myuser -f myscript.sql mydb
```

#### Using `pgpass`

On Linux, the file should be `$HOME/.pgpass`. On Windows, it's `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`.

This is a plain text file with this format:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

For example:

```
localhost:5432:mydb:myuser:mypassword
```