# PhpmyAdmin set user show only specific databases

Tags: mysql

I create a users in mysql and grant privilages of one databases but that account show me all databases and i easily delete other databases data.

Comment: When you log in as your new user from the command line (`mysql -u{username} -p`) and tell MySQL to show you the databases (`show databases;`), does it list all databases as well? If so, you probably granted privileges incorrectly.

Comment: yes this show all databases.

Comment: I would assume you granted the user access to `*.*` instead of `mydatabase.*`. Here's a question that might be helpful in your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database

Comment: thanks that help me.