# MYSQL Database Password Set

Tags: php, mysql, web

How can I set the database password for my sql database?

I am using ubuntu with apache, php, and my sql installed.

I followed this to create the database and import the sql file.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb

Now I need to get my code to connect to the database.

How do I set the database password? Or is that just the mysql root password?

Comment: This is the code I have to connect to the database...
$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'database_name';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = 'password';

Comment: is the question how do you set a password for MYSQL or how do you connect to a mysql database using username and password?

Comment: @Clint Well does each database get its own password? I keep getting error root@localhost access denied but I have set the password correctlyz

Comment: A database has users, the users have usernames and passwords. I still don't fully understand the original question you are asking.

Comment: @Clint I’m trying to connect my code to my database. Does each database have a username and password? I keep getting error root@localhost access denied

Comment: what is the database connection code that you are using?

Comment: @Clint check the first comment. I posted 3 lines. My password is the password I set when installing MySQL.

Comment: @Clint fixed it! Had to make an sql user and use that! Not the password you set during install!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new user in MySQL and give it full access to one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually create a my sql user and not use the password set when installing my sql on apache server.