# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mysql.JDBC - can't solve, mysql connector is added

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my code.
[image: This is my code.]

And this is the error i am getting. 
[image: and this is my error.]

Even though i added mysql connector to the database, which was the common solution for this problem, but i am still having it. Any advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use this `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` And rather than uploading pictures post your code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will!
This is what i got after i changed it with your suggestion:
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) .

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 1.6, JDBC 4.0 API provides a new feature to discover `java.sql.Driver` automatically and therefore `Class.forName` is no longer required.

Assuming `login` is the name of your database, use the following code in `getConnection`:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login?user=dbuser&password=dbpassword");
```

Comment: Now i got this one: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Different than before, now it has using password: yes..

Comment: Great! Do you have a database user as, `dbuser` with password as `dbpassword` with the required privileges? If not, first create them and test using a SQL client whether you can login to your database with these credentials. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database for help.