# MySQL SQL> ERROR: Not connected. Problem with creating a MySQL user

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I asked this question here an hour ago. I got a message that my question is closed, because it already has an answer here: [Create new user in MySQL and give it full access to one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database). However, I think this is a mistake because I didn't find anything relevant there! So I'm trying to ask again (hopefully that's okay):

I'm trying to create a database using MySQL.

I understand that I need to create a user to do so, and then I can create a database and use it in my python project. is that correct?

this is what I tried to run in the MySQL Shell:

```
MySQL  JS > \sql
MySQL  SQL > CREATE USER 'myname'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

I wanted to continue with:

```
 MySQL  SQL > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myname'@'localhost';
```

but I got this error- **ERROR: Not connected**

I looked up ways to fix it, but the only way I found was for people who already have a user.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: It's complaining about not being connected. How are you connecting?

Comment: @tadman How am I supposed to connect? I thought I was connecting by creating a user.

Comment: There's two parts to this: Your (network) connection to your server, and your authentication with the server. Both of these must be established, and in that order.

Comment: @tadman How do I do that?