# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'record'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'record'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mynk\config.php on line 7

Comment: You have put wrong password for your localhost server in your config.php file

Answer (score 1):

did you create record user?

```
CREATE USER 'record'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database_name.* To 'record'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or you can change that "record" user to "root" user

reference:[Create new user in MySQL and give it full access to one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database)