# How can I give rights to another database user?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello lovely community of Stackoverflow,
on a database I work on, we all share a single user (not root), and that is the only user it shows me on phpmyadmin. Logged onto that user I have all privileges. I can create a new user, but every time I want to give it all privileges or any even I get the error #1045 - Access denied...
So, can anyone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new user in MySQL and give it full access to one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database)

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html says:

> To grant a privilege with `GRANT`, you must have the `GRANT OPTION` privilege, and you must have the privileges that you are granting.

If you log in as your user and run `SHOW GRANTS` does it end `... WITH GRANT OPTION`?

If it does not, then you can't grant privileges to other users. You will have to get the owner of the database instance to do it.